# What to do with off-topic answers?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40929/did-russia-destroy-all-their-official-chemical-weapons) is about Russia's chemical weapons **in general**. However, [its highest-rated answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/40933/36738) specifically talks about the Novichok nerve agent, even though that is not mentioned at all by the asker. (It is entirely possible, in fact almost certain, that the question was precipitated by the ongoing incident allegedly caused by Noviochk, but the person asking it chose not to bring that up.)

In my opinion, that makes the answer off-topic, and hence irrelevant/invalid. However I am not sure what the procedure is (if any) for dealing with answers that don't actually answer the question at hand, on this SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is any subset of:

- Post a better answer.
- Downvote.
- Post a comment explaining the problem and suggesting solutions.
- Make an edit that fixes the problem.
- Flag for moderator attention.

In this case, the answer has been expanded by the author. You may find you are happy with it now.